# Is C++ appropriate for my application?

Tags: c++

I am developing a Windows desktop app, it allows users to create accounts and then login. Once logged in it allows them to interact with other users, and even has a chat box in a certain area. This app will eventually be ported over to android and ios(hopefully). Considering that it fetches quite a bit of information over the internet is C++ the most appropriate language to program it in?(i know quite a bit of c++, enough to make this) or should I use HTML5 or something else.

EDIT: For simplicity, essentially what I would like to know is. What is the EASIEST language to program an application in that will accept username/password and allow users to interact with one another. This program will also be accepting payments within it. I would like to use a language that is easily ported over to Android and IOS.

Comment: "Fetching data over the internet" is unlikely to happen so fast that it taxes whichever language you choose....  A great many languages can handle your requirements.

Comment: Perhaps C# is the choice for Windows desktop apps, I would use *anything* but C or C++.

Comment: since you want to port it to iOS and android via NDK, C++ is a good choice

Comment: Note the OP asks if C++ is appropriate. He does not ask whether something else is more appropriate. So a good answer is not about first choice, but whether you can state a good reason C++ is either a good choice or a poor choice.

Comment: @Keith Note the last line of the question.

Comment: I have edited my topic, hope I can receive more input.

Answer (score 3):

This is a question that doesn't really have a good answer. It's like asking what color you should paint the garden shed. There are many correct answers, and they are all subjective, and most likely based on the answerer's personal experiences.

If you have had experience with C++, then by all means go for it. C++ and it's related languages have the capability to create message windows and interact over the internet, so it is a good possibility for you.